# bower register error ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the path

Tags: git, github, bower, bower-register

I am using bower register in the following way:

```
bower register example https://github.com/example/example.git
```

An error appears:

```
register error ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the path
```

I am using git and have installed [gitbash](https://git-scm.com), I can push and commit to my online repository (using tortoisegit) but I still receive this error when using bower (any commands) from command line.

I am using Windows 8. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;

bower register example https://github.com/example/example.git
```

I hope can be useful to others.